# How can I run a batch file only one time per comptuer?

Tags: windows, script, batch

I have a batch file that I want to push out to make some changes, but the changes take a while and only need to be done one time, how can I manage this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a flag file. When the program first starts up, it checks if the flag is already there, and exits if it does. When the program is done, it creates the flag file.

```
SET FLAG=C:\Flag.txt
IF EXIST %FLAG% GOTO END

DO WORK > %FLAG%

:END
```

Comment: You could use the built-in `EOF` label rather then defining a new one.